# Everything above nth child

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select everything above a certain child, I have tried using gt: and slice yet can't get it to work. It has to be a selector which gets everything after a specific child, rather than removing the first child specifically. At the moment it is only taking out the second column, I need everything including and after the second column.

The line in question is:

```
var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent > :nth-child(2)')
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kL3c8/20/

```
<div class="partnerGroupContent group">

   <div class="column"> 
        <div class="sponsor">1</div>
        <div class="sponsor">2</div>
   </div>
    <div class="column"> 
        <div class="sponsor">3</div>
        <div class="sponsor">4</div>
   </div>
    <div class="column"> 
        <div class="sponsor">5</div>
        <div class="sponsor">6</div>
   </div>
    <div class="column"> 
        <div class="sponsor">7</div>
        <div class="sponsor">8</div>
   </div>

</div>

var rowCount = 2

var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent > :nth-child(2)')

if (rowCount == 2) {

        $('.partnerGroupContent').after(
        $('<div>', {
        'class': 'partnerGroupContent2'
         }).append(myColumn))

$('.partnerGroupContent').cycle();
$('.partnerGroupContent2').cycle();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:gt()`

```
$("div :gt(4)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:gt()` in jQuery.

- `:gt(n)` for greater than n
- `:lt(n)` for less than n
- `:eq(n)` for equal to n

  ```
  $("div :gt(4)").css("background-color", "colour name");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I tried did actually work:

```
var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent > :nth-child(n + 2)')
```

However the divs were hidden on top of each other which made it look like it wasn't working. Thank you for the help all the same.